# When the paho python mqtt client gets a message from subscribed topic, it always adds a "b" to the received message

Tags: python, client, mqtt

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

client.subscribe("test/#")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

When I receive a message it always adds a "b" to the message:
test/temperature **b**'test'

https://www.dinotools.de/2015/04/12/mqtt-mit-python-nutzen/

Comment: because it is an byte object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:
"bXXX" means bytes. You need to convert this to UTF-8 before using it:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.decode("utf-8")
```